# Correct way to place and handle .json file in Xcode

Tags: json, xcode, swift

I just started to learn Swift and xcode and the first problem that I'm facing is how and where should I place the json file ? And how to use those files? Should I place the .json files within Assets folder ? Since I find it  difficult, I would love to hear some tips or examples from you !

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can add an `empty file`, select `syntax coloring` as `JSON` and paste your json text. Even if it is not formatted, you can format it by selecting all the text and pressing `Ctrl + I`.

[image]

Answer (score 17):

How I've done this in September 2019...

1) In Xcode, create an `Empty` file. Give the file a `.json` suffix

2) Type in or paste in your JSON

3) Click `Editor` -> `Syntax Coloring` -> `JSON`

4) Inside the file, highlight the JSON, click `ctrl + i` to indent

5) `import SwiftyJSON` using Cocoapods

6) In your ViewController, write...

```
guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "File", ofType: "json") else { return }

let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)

do {  

    let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)

    let json = try JSON(data: data)

} catch {

    print(error)
}
```

N.B. - `"File"` is the name of the file you created, but excluding the `.json` suffix

See SwiftyJSON GitHub page for more info - https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON

Comment: descriptive and great answer

Answer (score 9):

Please review the below image to check where to place the file.
I suggest you to create a group and add the file in that.[image]

After that, review the below could for using that file.

Edit: This is the updated code for Swift 5 if that helps anyone.

```
    let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "filename", ofType: "json")
    let jsonData = try? NSData(contentsOfFile: path!, options: NSData.ReadingOptions.mappedIfSafe)
```

Comment: Thank you Kalra ! Can I ask one more question ? With what or How will I read the json array or strings from the jsonData ?

Answer (score 4):

```
var location = "test"
var fileType = "json"
if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: location, ofType: fileType) {
        do {
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path), options: .alwaysMapped)
            let jsonObj = JSON(data: data)
            if jsonObj != JSON.null {
            }
        } catch let error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement, you want to read json from that json file.

I am using SWIFTY JSON Library for that.

Find below the link for that

https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON

Add this library to your project.

After adding it, now review the below code:-

```
let json = JSON(data: jsonData!)
for (index, subjson): (String, JSON) in json{
    let value = subjson["key"].stringValue
}
```